# Azure Storage account API: List (recursive) only directories in account - not files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I want to be able to query an Azure storage account and pull back a list of only the directories/folders under a container, rather than the entire contents including blobs/files.

I want to do this so I can then export the ACLs for each of those folders.

I've tried a few options:

`Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Recurse` returns all folders AND files. You can filter each item on IsDirectory -eq $true, but because of the maximum item limit, the need for a continuation token, and a generally slow response time, this takes a long time amount of time if your container has hundreds of thousands of files.

Using the storage API - querying the below endpoint - also returns all files/folders, with no way to filter the response.

https://STORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER?comp=list&prefix=one%2F&maxresults=5000&restype=container&include=metadata&delimiter=%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about PowerShell commands for this, but the API ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)) does support a `showonly=directories` parameter.

This does require that you have hierarchical namespaces enabled, but I assume you do since you mentioned folder ACLs.